# How to Focus to parent window when a Treenode is clicked in child window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a javascript to open a pop-up window. The pop-up window contains treeview nodes and when the treeview node is clicked, it must open another link in the previous window and the focus must be set on it. I used below codes to open a pop-up window which works good..

```
 function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) 
 {    
   var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
   var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
   var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);

    if (targetWin.location == "about:blank")
      {
         targetWin.location.href=pageURL;
         targetWin.focus();
      }
    else
      {
        targetWin.focus();            
      }
 }
```

Below is the code I used for redirecting to previous window and opening a new page..

```
function returnToPrevWindow()
{
 var targetwin = opener.document.location.href='DisplayNotificationContent.aspx';
 targetwin.focus();
}
```

What happens is whenever I clicked the treenode in the pop-up, it go back to previous window and open the page that must open but it didn't focus on it, the focus was still on the pop-up window..the targetwin.focus() on function returnToPrevWindow() doesn't work.

What should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: declare targetwin variable out side function.

Comment: i tried doing that already...declaring outside function but it still doesn't focus